# Using cookies in Angular with a flask API backend

Tags: angular, cookies, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to store session cookies for an angular application with a flask backend. In the session I set the following

```
this.cookieService.set('loggedIn', true);
this.cookieService.set('username', username);
this.cookieService.set('uid', uid);
```

and in from flask I get a is logged in true.

When I try to get anything else that requires login it says that is `None` which I'm guessing is because the browser is not sending any actual cookie in the header because no cookie is being stored by Angular.

I also tested this in postman and the data from flask returned the correct user.

How can I store the cookie in the browser and do I need to send it from the backend?

Comment: can you share the cookieService code?

Comment: I can tell you that we had some issues with cookieService, its not working very well.

Comment: @MahinKhan it's an ngx package npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: try with additional arguments `this.cookieService.set("token_name", token, 900000, "/", "", true, "Strict");` arguments are as follows: name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite?: 'Lax' | 'Strict' )